# linkedin messages website preview where does it come from when using messages?

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph, open-graph-beta

I have website which we manualy share links on social media platforms including linkedin. Then we created a business page in linkedin. then suddenly when we send our website url to different people via linkedin messages the preview is different from the og:image set on the website. can someone confirm if linkedin fetches the profile picture instead once the business page related to the website is created?

I did try using OpenGraph debugger and confirmed my og tags are correct as reflected. but in the preview in the linkedin messages its different.